# Denotational semantics of while-loops

Tags: denotational-semantics

At section 5.2 of 2000’s republication of 1974’s paper [‘Continuations: A Mathematical Semantics for Handling Full Jumps’](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/cs257/archive/christopher-strachey/continuations.pdf) by Christopher Strachey and Christopher Wadsworth, the following denotational semantic equation is given (to show that the following block command is equivalent to the while-loop command $\textbf{while}\ \epsilon\ \textbf{do}\ \gamma$):

$$\mathcal{P}[\![§\ \textbf{dummy};\, \xi\!:\, \epsilon \rightarrow (\gamma;\, \textbf{goto}\ \xi),\, \textbf{dummy}\ §]\!]\rho\theta = \theta_0$$

where

- $\theta_0 = \mathcal{P}[\![\textbf{dummy}]\!]\rho'\theta_1$;
- $\theta_1 = \mathcal{P}[\![\epsilon \rightarrow (\gamma;\, \textbf{goto}\ \xi),\, \textbf{dummy}]\!]\rho'\theta$;
- $\rho' = \rho[\theta/\xi]$.

With the new environment $\rho′ = \rho[\theta/\xi]$, my understanding is that the jump command $\textbf{goto}\ \xi$ will jump to the end of the block command instead of the point labelled by the identifier $\xi$, since the command continuation $\theta$ denoted by $\xi$ in that new environment is the state transformation from the end of the block command to the end of the program. So I would expect the new environment to be $\rho′ = \rho[\theta_1/\xi]$, since the command continuation $\theta_1$ denoted by $\xi$ in that new environment would be the state transformation from the point labelled by $\xi$ to the end of the program. Is it a typo?